# Inset Values at Table

Tags: sql, insert, sql-insert, bulkinsert

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyDqY.png)

why i am getting this error.

Comment: Too much ALL CAPS -  hard to read, so people may not.

Comment: That's correct. Specify columns if you don't want all of them.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all information directly to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your HireDate Date datatype won't just accept string. You need to explicitly mention Date keyword while inserting date value (Please make sure that the DATE keyword will follow the format YYYY-MM-DD). Also you need to mention year as well. Try something like below:

```
Insert INTO Employees (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, DepartmentID, Salary, HireDate)
VALUES (1, 'NARESH', 'GUDLA', 987, 4400, DATE '2018-05-07');
```